# DeflateStream doesnt work on MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream, deflate, binary-serialization

I have the following piece of code:

```
MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
string users = ""//Really long string goes here
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream assignedUsersStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bFormatter.Serialize(assignedUsersStream, users);
    assignedUsersStream.Position = 0;

    using (var compressionStream =
        new DeflateStream(resultStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        assignedUsersStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);

        Console.WriteLine("Compressed from {0} to {1} bytes.",
            assignedUsersStream.Length.ToString(),
            resultStream.Length.ToString());
    }
}
```

the thing is that `resultStream` is always empty!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put your verification WriteLine outside of the using.  The buffers haven't been flushed yet.

```
using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(resultStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
{
    assignedUsersStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);

    //Console.WriteLine("Compressed from {0} to {1} bytes.",
    //       assignedUsersStream.Length.ToString(), resultStream.Length.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine("Compressed from {0} to {1} bytes.",
     assignedUsersStream.Length, resultStream.ToArray().Length);
```

And aside, you don't need all those `ToString()`s in a writeline.

PS: All a BinaryFormatter  does with a string is write the bytes with length prefix. If you don't need the prefix (my guess), it could become:

```
string users = "";//Really long string goes here
byte[] result;  

using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(resultStream,
             CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        byte[] inBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(users);
        compressionStream.Write(inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.Length);
    }
    result = resultStream.ToArray();
}
```

The reverse is just as easy but you'll need an estimate of the maximum length to create the read-buffer:

```
string users2 = null;

using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream(result))
{
    using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new  DeflateStream(resultStream,
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        byte[] outBuffer = new byte[2048];   // need an estimate here
        int length = compressionStream.Read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.Length);
        users2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outBuffer, 0, length);                        
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 12):

That is because the `DeflateStream` doesn't flush the data to the underlying stream until it is closed. After it is closed, `resultStream` will contain the compressed data. Note that by default, `DeflateStream` closes the underlying stream when it's closed, but you don't want that, so you need to pass `true` for the `leaveOpen` parameter. Also, you don't need 2 memory streams, you can just serialize directly to the `compressionStream`:

```
    string users = ""; //Really long string goes here
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(resultStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
        {
            bFormatter.Serialize(compressionStream, users);
            Console.WriteLine(resultStream.Length); // 0 at this point
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultStream.Length); // now contains the actual length
    }
```

Comment: The stream doesn't have to stay open, ToArray() will work fine on a closed MemoryStream. But agreed on serializing directly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, you're right; I was getting an exception when accessing the stream's Length, but ToArray works fine.

Answer (score 2):

From the original answer (I don't have enough credits to vote down)

> Put your control WriteLine outside of the using

**This is incomplete and IMO therefore misleading**. `DeflateStream`'s `Dispose(bool)` implementation `Close`s the underlying `resultStream` when the `DeflateStream` is being `Finalized` after it's been Garbage Collected. When this happens, `resultStream.Length` will throw:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

In other words, Thomas Levesque's note is critical: **also set `leaveOpen` to `true`**.

An interesting question with some good points raised by HH and TL.

Comment: I didn't see this before but accessing the stream after disposing it is quite allright, __a long as it is a MemoryStream__ . That wasn't clear in my first snippet but it's in the second, longer one and in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've come in late to this as I ran into this same problem and reading the conflicting answers.  The initial response works! as does this test *(over simplified to highlight the answer)*:

```cs
var inStream = new MemoryStream(data);
var outStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(outStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
{
    inStream.CopyTo(compressor);
}
return outStream;
```

where the `using` block needs to complete, triggering the compressor's `Dispose`, which internally `Flush()`es so that `outStream` will be guaranteed to contain the complete compressed data.